# What is the difference between panic and an assert?

Tags: go

> [Go doesn't provide assertions. They are undeniably convenient, but our experience has been that programmers use them as a crutch to avoid thinking about proper error handling and reporting.](https://golang.org/doc/faq#assertions)

However it has [print and println](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Bootstrapping) which does

> panic      like print, aborts execution after printing
>   panicln    like println, aborts execution after printing

Isnt that the same thing as an assert? Why would they claim the above but have panic? i can see it leading to the same problems but adding an error msg to the end of it which can easily be abused. Am i missing something?

Comment: No, it's not. `panic` is like "write then abort", while an assert is like "test and if it's false, write then abort". There's no way they can keep you from doing an assert-like statement anyways.

Comment: zneak: to bad your comment isnt an answer :D

Comment: I'll turn that into an answer if it's so great.

Comment: Saying that "programmers use them as a crutch" is like saying that we programmers are so dumb that we'd use a burglar alarm for a calling bell.

Comment: @Agnel Dumber than that because it totally fails to grasp the difference between program logic errors, and other errors, which are in very different spaces. In a properly written program, *every* possible non-logic error is anticipated, checked for, and reported. But of course it is impossible to anticipate every possible logic error. Also, by requiring explicit checks rather than providing exceptions, they guarantee that real programs will miss some errors, and they impose an overhead on every check. The unreliable Unix technology that doesn't detect I/O errors is repeated here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it's not. panic is like "write then abort", while an assert is like "test and if it's false, write then abort". There's no way they can keep you from doing an assert-like statement anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the obvious, that `panic` does not check anything while `assert` does, in Go you can use mechanics for error handling, even when a panic occurs.

If a package thinks something occurs that can not be recovered from it panics.

However, the package-user, the caller (parent level) may either want to inspect or log a panic and then continue to panic, or catch it to properly handle the case (for example, try again or then use a different package/function).

Also, an assert-abort does not call destructors or anything. A panic in Go though will still call even the functions you `defer` will be executed, so everything is cleaned up.

So, as you can see, a panic will allow for a variety of cleanup-tasks in contrast to asserts. That’s what the quote you gave was pointing to.

For good information on defer, panic and recover, see [the official blog post on them](http://blog.golang.org/2010/08/defer-panic-and-recover.html).

Answer (score 1):

For one, in C, `assert()` only aborts execution when in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, and that's a terribly wrong behavior, perhaps the exact one Google wants to prevent. Why would you want to let your program continue running after it's blantantly done something wrong?

Comment: To be exact, assert abort exectution unless the preprocessor NDEBUG macro is defined.  It is still possible to have assert outside of debug builds if you so choose.

Comment: First, "Google" doesn't want anything here, only some people who happen to work at Google. Second, they can't prevent anything -- with no assert in the language, people will simply leave them out of their programs. It isn't a matter of wanting your program to continue after doing something wrong -- that's a silly strawman. Rather, it's not wanting to pay the cost of doing checks that always fail in correct programs. Assertions are a way to turn incorrect programs into correct programs.