# Handling assertion in Golang in a similar way to panic

Tags: go, assertion

I’ve two functions, an outer one which invokes a second function defined on a separate library. That library function might fail and I'd like to be able to handle such error properly.

The code looks like this:

```
func myFunction(...) ... {
     defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            do_some_recovery_step
        }
    }()
    libraryFunction(...)
}
```

That library looks like this:

```
func libraryFunction(...) ... {
    ...
    require.NoError(some_condition)
    ... 
}
```

In which case my “recovery step” doesn’t work at all when the error is triggered. However, if I modify that library function to use `panic` instead of `require.NoError`, as this:

```
func libraryFunction(...) ... {
    ...
    if some_error_condition {
        panic("Error happened")
    }
    ... 
}
```

the recovery process now works.

Now, the thing is, although I have access to the `libraryFunction` sources, that function is used by others, and I wouldn't want to modify its behavior if possible as somebody might rely on the current one; instead, I'd prefer to properly handle the error condition on my own function.

I was under the impression that `require.NoError` was basically some kind of fancier version of `panic` (as I understood from this article: [What is the difference between panic and an assert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165369/what-is-the-difference-between-panic-and-an-assert)), but I might be wrong (I'm a beginner in Golang, so I understand my assumptions might be completely wrong).

So, my main question is: Is it possible in Golang to handle assertions (like the ones triggered from the `require` package shown here) like the way it can handle `panics`? Or if not similar, is there another possible way to do this without having to modify the library generating the assertion?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: require.NoError is primarily used in the context of unit testing to assert that no error has occurred. On the other hand, panic is used for unexpected errors during the normal operation of the application, typically indicating a state from which the application cannot recover on its own. The advantage of Go is that it allows functions to return an error value and handle it explicitly by checking whether the error is nil or not, which is the most common approach to error handling.

Comment: The problem in this case is that the inner function generating the panic or the assertion might not always be under our control, so, regardless how good our own practices are, we need to handle cases where the external code is not that good following those practices.  That becomes mandatory the necessity to explore other ways to properly handle such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, `require.NoError(t, ...)` (from [testify](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/require)) appears to call `t.FailNow()`, which then calls `runtime.Goexit()`; this one seems to always ignore `recover` operation because it's not a [panic](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/runtime/panic.go;l=560). So, you can't really use `recover` in your case.

So, what you're trying to catch here (or recover from) is not really a panic. In case you want to "recover" from a failing `require.NoError(t, ...)` in your `libraryFunction`, you can always use the [`t.Cleanup`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Cleanup) function, and trigger your "recovery" only if test has failed:

```golang
func myFunction(t *testing.T) {
    t.Cleanup(func() {
        if t.Failed() { // ONLY IF libraryFunction fails
            fmt.Println("recovery!") // trigger the "recovery"
        }
    })
    libraryFunction(t)
}
```

That way, if `libraryFunction` fails, your code will pass in `fmt.Println("recovery!")` (or whatever your recovery step is). If `libraryFunction` pass (`require.NoError` does not fail), your recovery step won't run.

You can check a working example here: https://go.dev/play/p/N6xSqDJV1A6.